# Does this sentence sound ok?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have the following sentence:

> Let us recall the functionality of watch `-` it tells you the time when
>   you want to know.

Is it ok to use `-` here? Or should I use

> Let us recall the functionality of watch`:` it tells you the time when
>   you want to know.

Comment: I believe either is correct, but the second one seems a bit better, because you're presenting what the functionality of watch is, instead of just stating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two independent clauses, so use a semi-colon. You would not use a colon because it is followed by a single item, not a list.

> Let us recall the functionality of *a* watch; it tells you the time when you want to know *it*.

Comment: or may I say "Let us recall the functionality of a watch, which is to tell you the time when you want to know it."